# monitor multiple server load averages

Tags: multi-monitor, top

I'm helping to manage around 6 linux servers that host public websites. I'd like to monitor the live load averages (e.g. using TOP) and have these display in a Windows GUI that takes up minimal space on the monitor (e.g. a thin bar at the top of the screen?).

Currently I'm using Super Putty, which is OK, but big.  If possible, would like to find an open source solution that allows just load averages (e.g. CPU / mem) similar to [mmonit](https://mmonit.com/).  I've looked at [PuttyTabs](https://www.raisin.de/putty-tabs/putty-tabs.html) but it seems very out of date (last update 2007).